# Django: Returning boolean whether a value exist in ManyToManyField or not

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have two models ModelA and ModelB.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.field1

Class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dogs  = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)
```

I want to check in django view that whether an object 'o' of ModelB already has some value for field 'dogs'.

For example if there is an object 'o' of ModelB whose value for field 'name' is 'Ankit' and value for field 'dogs' is ['Labra' , 'Rottweiler' and 'Pug']. I want to check whether o.dogs has 'Labra' or not. How can i achieve this? Since 'dogs' field is ManyToMany field so when i use

```
ModelB.objects.all().values('dogs')
```

What i get is the following result:

```
<QuerySet [{'dogs': 1}, {'dogs': 2}, {'dogs': 3}]>
```

I do not how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
dogs_list = ['Labra' , 'Rottweiler', 'Pug']
ModelB.objects.filter(dogs__multivalues__in=dogs_list).exists()
```

Which returns `True` if exists and `False` if it does not exist.
If you want to check for particular dog you can do:

```
dog_name = 'Labra'
ModelB.objects.filter(dogs__multivalues=dog_name).exists()
```

Comment: Where have you passed the query whether 'Labra' for a particular object exists or not in values of field2 for that object?

Comment: I think you have checked for a list of dogs instead of a single dog.

Comment: @AshokKumar please see my updated answer. I added case for looking for a single dog if exists query.

Comment: Sir, I am thankful that you are devoting your time to help me out but I am getting False for those values that exists.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many field is associated with a queryset, which exposes the normal Query API. So if you have a ModelB object `o` and you want to check its `dogs` field for a specific name, you can do:

```
o.dogs.filter(multivalues='Labra')
```

(I'm not sure why the field is called "multivalues", though. Does it have multiple values in it? If so, why - the multiple elements functionality is already provided by the many-to-many field.)

**Edit**

To check a field contains a value, use the `__contains` filter:

```
o.dogs.filter(multivalues__contains='Labra')
```

But really, as I say, you shouldn't have multiple values in a single field; that is what the m2m relationship is for.

Comment: What if i want to whether any object of ModelB contains 'Labra'  in field2 or not ? In this case i want to check for every object of ModelB that it contains 'Labra' in its field2 or not.. Thanks @DanielRoseman for your reply.

Comment: I have changed the field name Sir @DanielRoseman and i did perform makemigrations and migrate in actual code.I request you to change field name so as others won't get confused. Though it's entirely my mistake.